# Start Third Library Apps on my Device from Meteor

Tags: meteor, startup

Is it possible to start/open an another App on the device with my created Meteor app.

The aim here is that I want start some other apps from my Meteor app there are installen on my Android phone or IOS phone.

Something like these: https://github.com/venkykowshik/startapp

Comment: i mean open other native or hybrid apps on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Ok im found something with that you can open a webbrowser from the device

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html#more-usage-info

... but only the webbrowser.. i need something where i can open everything with the packagename of the application on the device.. nobody have an idea?